# Google Sheet: Filtering multiple values in a single cell

Tags: regex, filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to filter a column and the result should contain both the word `"biology"` and `"aqa"`.

I'm using this formula now:

```
=regexmatch(A:A, "biology|aqa"
```

But the result also contains words that have `biology` or `aqa` only like:

- biology-a2-unit-1
- biology-a2-unit-4
- biology-alevel
- aqa-alevel
- alevel-aqa-unit-1

My expected result should  have both `"biology"` and `"aqa"` only like:

- biology-aqa
- biology-aqa-a-level
- biology-aqa-gcse
- as-biology-aqa
- aqa-biology-gcse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using `|` which is `OR` logic. but you need `AND` logic

```
=FILTER(A:A, REGEXMATCH(A:A, "aqa"), REGEXMATCH(A:A, "biology"))
```

[image: 0]